# How to check the value on the array cart

Tags: codeigniter

I have an array cart on codeigniter and creates a function to separate if there is engrave or not on the array like this,

```
$cart_count = 0;
$cart_cek = $this->cart->contents();

foreach ($cart_cek as $value2) {
      if($cart_count >= 1){
        break;
      }
      else{
        if($value2['engrave-text'] != ""){
          $order_id = $this->generate_order_id_costume();
          $cart_count++;
        }
        else{
          $order_id = $this->generate_order_id();
          $cart_count++;
        }
      }
    }
```

but when I run the function it always goes into else with value

`$order_id = $this->generate_order_id();`

even though there is engrave in the cart array.

For example, I have 3 items in the cart that each have the engrave field. How do I know that there are at least 1 engrave field filled in all the carts?

Comment: Did you try `empty()` or `isset()`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to check the count to stop the loop and try using `isset()`.

Try this if you want to check if `$this->cart->contents();` has at least 1 `engrave-text` object.

```php
$cart = $this->cart->contents();

foreach ($cart as $cart_value) {
    if(isset($cart_value['engrave-text'])){
        $order_id = $this->generate_order_id_costume();
    } else {
        $order_id = $this->generate_order_id();
    }
}
```

Comment: I always go to the if section

Comment: okay, then I think you don't need the break? I will edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that if the cart contains at least one `engrave-text` field is filled, you could use `array_column` to get the `engrave-text` arrays, then `array_filter` to check if it's empty :

```
$cart_cek = $this->cart->contents();
if (!empty(array_filter(array_column($cart_cek, 'engrave-text')))) { // if at least one 'engrave-text' has a value, call generate_order_id_costume() method
    $order_id = $this->generate_order_id_costume();
} else { // otherwise call generate_order_id() method
    $order_id = $this->generate_order_id();
}
```

Comment: I always go to the else section

Comment: so the whole `'engrave-text'` is empty? do you want to check if it's empty or if it's not empty?

Comment: it's not empty it will go into generate_order_id_costume();

Comment: are you sure that the `engrave-text` is not empty? could you share your cart sample data?